# Export/Import cPanel "Account Level Filtering" rules

Tags: email, filter, cpanel, spam, spam-prevention

I am using the cPanel "Account Level Filtering" functionality to block incoming mail from spamming servers and email addresses. Throughout the years I have created an extensive list of rules to block specific spammers.

I would like to know if there is a way to export the "Account Level Filtering" rules and have a backup file of them.

I also wonder if it's possible to import the filtering rules to a cPanel account (through WHM or terminal) instead of adding them one by one manually through cPanel.

Comment: +1 because i have an aggressive filter for spammers. I need to export it for my other accounts and servers.

Comment: `http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/using-one-account-level-filtering-file-across-my-vps-407601.html` a good start for spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/vfilters/domain.com contains all your account level filters. You can make a copy of that. If you do not have root access to the server, ask your hosting company to provide you with a copy of this file.

Comment: That directory/file structure is incorrect on my servers. 
For Box Trapper filters look in:
/etc/domainname.com/mailboxname/.boxtrapper/ 

For Global Email Filter files: filter.cache and filter.yaml...
find those in the /.cpanel/ directory

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to backup and restore email forwarders configuration and email filters configuration using 'Backup Wizard' tool available in main cPanel menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and wanted to share some fairly extensive Global Email Filters to various websites instead of replicating all the filter rules manually, which would take days.  Using the Backup wizard did not work for this: when I imported the email filter files into another website it generated a user incompatibility error.

Instead, I logged into cpanel on the original website:

I opened file manager.

Then I opened the folder: .cpanel

(If you can't see this folder, click on settings then check the box next to 'Show Hidden Files (dotfiles)' and click Save).

Then I downloaded these two files:

filter.cache

filter.yaml

then uploaded those two files to the same location in the cpanel of the new websites.

Note: I had not created ANY spam filters in the new (recipient) websites so the new files were a clean upload, not an over-write of previous files.  If you have already created spam filters in the recipient site, then uploading the files saved from the donor site will overwrite them.